# How often per second does Windows do a thread switch?

Tags: .net, windows, multithreading

How often does Windows (usually) do a thread switch per second? Is this different from .NET threads? Or asked the other way around: How long is a thread (of, say, normal thread priority) allowed to run?

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_scheduling_2.shtml

Comment: Can you describe the practical programming problem you're trying to solve? Are you trying to speed up context switches? Reduce them?

Comment: @HansPassant - not imprssed by your ref - read the first couple lines, only to find it mentions 'a quantum, or number of allocated timeslices of CPU' before it mentions I/O.  Didn't bother reading any further.  Yet another hopelessly misleading and badly-organized threading intro.

Comment: @MartinJames I don't see that quote anywhere in what Hans referenced.  But, what has the definition of quantum got to do with I/O?

Comment: @RaymondChen I was wondering, in a system of two concurrent threads, whether I can put a thread to sleep for 1 millisecond. I figured, if each thread gets at least,say, 15 ms to execute I would never be able to sleep for just 1 ms (but always for at least 15 ms). See my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321225/net-thread-sleep-is-randomly-imprecise

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski You other post seems to deal with timed operations.  I would suggest using a timer, not trying to sleep threads.  Sleeping threads are threads that are still "in use", a timer can use a thread pool to more efficiently use threads, plus, depending on the timer, you can get more accurate timing.

Comment: In general, you should ask questions about your specific problem rather than asking vague questions about something more complicated than your problem. The resolution of timing is based on the clock tick, and Windows typically runs the clock at 10 to 15 ms.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How often Windows context switches depends on the system "quantum".  This quantum ranges from 10-15 milliseconds (66-100 times per second) depending on whether the OS is client or server.  For more detail I recommend reading Joe Duffy's book *Concurrent Programming on Windows*; it goes into great detail about things like this--e.g. details that "client OSes ... is 2 clock intervals.  ...on server OSes... is 12 clock intervals".  Also, his article [CLR Inside Out: Using concurrency for scalability][1] is a must read.

You can sort of "edit" the quantum length.  If you set the "Adjust for best performance of:" in Performance Options/Advanced in System Properties to "Programs", you'll get a shorter quantum.  If you set it to "Background services" you'll get a longer quantum.

If there's no reason to context switch, a thread will get as much time as it needs.

[1] http://www.360doc.cn/article/28217_2474333.html

Comment: 'How often Windows context switches depends on the system "quantum" - NO!  Not on 99% of Windows boxes,(those not overloaded and not running CPU-intensive apps), it doesn't.

Comment: @MartinJames You only have a context switch when something needs to switch away from a thread to another, this only happens if the system has oversubscribed the CPUs.  If the system doesn't need to give a thread time to execute (e.g. the system is not under heavy load and it hasn't oversubscribed) then no context switch needs to occur.  i.e. you're talking about two different things.  Whether the system *needs* to context switch is different than how often id *does*

Comment: @MartinJames of course you can "force" a context switch with `Thread.Sleep(timeout >= 1)`, but that's a different story :)

Comment: Someone said 'A context-switch IS "process of saving or restoring this state from and to the hardware".'  This occurs every time a thread that was blocked on I/O is made ready by a driver signal. The context has changed from 'IO waiting' to 'ready', (and, hopefully, 'running').  Its state is restored from the hardware - a context-switch by your definition :)

Comment: Again, yes, a context switch *can* occur when a thread blocked on IO becomes unblocked because the IO completed.  But, context-switches occur for other reasons too, one of which is the the OS schedules a CPU-bound thread due to processor over-subscription.  Yes, that might be rare and you can design code to avoid it; but, it still happens.  And when it *does* happen, it happens at a certain frequence.

Comment: OTOH, I have now read the extra comments by the OP and it's pretty clear now that he is interested in timers/sleeps and the title alone does not make that clear :(  So, yes, you're stuck with the timer granularity issue, as you corretly post.

Comment: Wrong. A *clock interval* is 10 *or* 15.6 ms (100 *or* **64** times a second), and a quantum is 2 or 12 clock intervals, depending on the OS type (default). Typically, a thread will last for 20 ms, 30 ms, or 180 ms, so there are typically 50, 33, or 5.5 context switches a second.

Answer (score 1):

`A context switching rate of 300 per second per processor is a moderate amount` says in the [source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938613.aspx).

Windows2000 has [Pviewer utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938606.aspx) to measure that.

Comment: Just to expand on this: Windows doesn't do this at a constant rate. It's adaptive depending on the current load. Context switches are expensive so excessive numbers of them have a performance impact.

Comment: Yepp, even the cpu itself changes the frequeny dynmically we cannot foresee what is what.

Answer (score 0):

On a typical system, this is highly dependent on the I/O loading.  Much disk and network activity will generate a lot of context-switches as threads call for I/O, get blocked and are later made ready again.  The complexity and design of the running apps also affects context-switch rate - apps with a lot of threads, many locks, excessive work inside locks, too much inter-thread comms compared with the size of communicated data, silly polling etc. will drive up the context-change rate.

On most systems, most of the time, the stuff about 'quantum', 'time-slice' etc. is irrelevant - just a footnote in I/O-driven preemptive multitasking that only occurs regularly on boxes with more ready, CPU-intensive, threads than cores, ie. those that are grossly overloaded or run CPU-intensive apps.

A thread of normal priority is allowed to run until it is prempted, usually by it electing to wait on I/O or signaling from another thread.  Even if it does no I/O or signaling, ie. is completely CPU-bound, it may still run forever if the box is never overloaded, (ie never has more ready threads than cores).

Comment: A context-switch IS "process of saving or restoring this state from and to the hardware".  While IO can incur context switching, context switching is **not** dependent on IO.  A context-switch must occur when one thread is a candidate for CPU time and no CPUs are currently available (in use by another thread).  A context switch also occurs when you call `Thread.Sleep` with a timeout greater than 0.  When the system gives CPU to a thread, that occurs at a rate defined by the quantum.

Comment: No one is saying switching occurs out of the blue, it happens for a reason.  And when it happens, there's a granularity to how often it *can* happen.

Comment: Look,  context switch can only occur when the OS is entered. It can only be entered by an interrupt, either a 'real' driver interrupt, (by far the most important), or an OS call that can change the set of running threads.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that the OS cannot schedule a thread to run without some sort of I/O interrupt or a thread relinquishing control.  If you have 8 cores and 9 CPU-bound thread and none of them are causing any interrupts, the OS will still schedule time for pre-empted threads.  While IO interrupts may influence thread scheduling, thread scheduling isn't dependant on it. "...the Windows OS uses preemptive scheduling for all threads on the system, also known as time-slicing" If that's what you mean, than you're not saying anything different than anyone else.

Comment: On most systems, context-switches occur almost exclusively upon I/O.  Certainly, the box on which I write this is in that state.  There is no 'quantum' associated with its operation because all the 1154 threads are waiting on I/O or each other and no 4 threads are going to run for long enough to approach being scheduled out just because of a timer-generated scheduling run. It's all I/O driven unless I put a large CPU loading on the box, then there may be some extra context-switches due to more long-running ready threads than cores.

Comment: I/O interrupts are absolutely at the core of thread scheduling. Just because a timer interrupt occurs that may, on a CPU-overloaded box with many long-running threads, shuffle round the set of ready threads so that a different set is then run, (yes, that's a context change), doesn't change the fact that most Windows boxes are not overloaded and most threads run for short periods upon I/O driver signals or signals from other threads.  There is no 'granularity' on most systems - the threads are made ready and run until they are blocked again.

Comment: There's many reasons why context-switches occur.  "almost exclusively" just confuses your point.  The fact is that when Windows *does* schedule a thread that wasn't caused by IO, it occurs at a certain frequency influenced by the "quantum".  No one is saying context switch *don't* occur for different reasons or that if there's enough CPU, context-switching is mostly irrelevant, we're talking about when Windows schedules a thread for execution because that thread hasn't had CPU time (i.e. doesn't current have the CPU) and *is* CPU bound. Yes, we're talking about large CPU loading.

Comment: Forget my comments - I've now read the extra OP comments and, taking these into account, rather than just the original title, I/O interrupts are irellevant to the OP's REAL question :)