# .NET Thread.Sleep() is randomly imprecise

Tags: .net, multithreading

In my .NET application I have to replay a series of sensor events. So I created a thread that fires these events (usually about every 1 - 4 millisecond). I implemented a loop in this thread and used `Thread.Sleep(...)` to put the thread to sleep between the events.

Basically it looks like this:

```
void RunThread() {
  var iter = GetAllEvents().GetEnumerator();
  if (!iter.MoveNext()) {
    return;
  }

  DateTime lastEventTime = iter.Current.Timestamp;
  FireEvent(iter.Current);

  while (iter.MoveNext()) {
    MyEvent nextEvent = iter.Current;

    int timeout = (int)(nextEvent.Timestamp - lastEventTime).TotalMilliseconds; 
    Thread.Sleep(timeout);

    FireEvent(nextEvent);
    lastEventTime = nextEvent.Timestamp;
  }
}
```

**Now, my problem is that `Thread.Sleep()` sometimes respects the specified timeout and sometimes it doesn't.**

I added a check (using `StopWatch`, not visible in the code above) on how long the sleep actually took. Here are some results:

```
Expected timeout of 1 ms but got 15 ms.
Expected timeout of 2 ms but got 13 ms.
Expected timeout of 3 ms but got 15 ms.
Expected timeout of 2 ms but got 13 ms.
Expected timeout of 1 ms but got 13 ms.
Expected timeout of 1 ms but got 15 ms.
Expected timeout of 2 ms but got 13 ms.
Expected timeout of 2 ms but got 40 ms.
```

Why does `Thread.Sleep()` behave that "randomly"?

Notes:

- The Window task manager doesn't show any cpu usage while this thread runs.
- The behavior changes randomly but persists for at least a couple of seconds. For example, one time when I start the thread, it does run fine. The next time it runs slow the whole time. The next time it runs fast for a couple of seconds, than slows down or the other way around.

**Update:** Here's some pseudo-code that shows how `Sleep` behaves:

```
bool ChooseRespectTimeout() {
  if (this.notYetChosen) {
    this.respectTimeout = ChooseRandomly()
    this.notYetChosen = false
    reset this.notYetChosen after random time period
  }
  return this.respectTimeout
}

void Sleep(int timeout) {
  if (ChooseRespectTimeout())
    Thread.Sleep(timeout)
  else
    Thread.Sleep(timeout * 10)
}
```

Comment: I don't know why they haven't updated the documentation for that method.  that method really just calls Sleep http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx which details the lack of accuracy.

Comment: What `Thread.Sleep` really does is give up control for *about* the specified milliseconds.  That could be more or less.  The rate at which the OS can give back control is determined by the system quantum, which is 10-15 milliseconds.  So, in reality `Thread.Sleep` can only be accurate to the nearest quantum.  But, as others have pointed out, if the CPU is under heavy load that time will be longer.  Plus, if your thread has a lower priority than all other threads, it may not get time.

Comment: Long story short, only use `Thread.Sleep` to let other applications/threads have a time slice and only use Thread.Sleep(1) to do that.  http://bit.ly/IhxHSk i.e. don't use `Thread.Sleep` for timing.

Comment: I've already changed my implementation. I'm still curious about why it behaves that way. Like I state in the question there no notable CPU load (so that's not the problem). Also, the thread has the highest priority and still exhibits this strange behavior.

Comment: well, it's about load when the switch should occur.  you're talking about a 1ms timeout (which is really about 15, as you've witnessed, due to the system quantum) which means that he OS really only needs to be busy for 15-30 ms before it can be to busy to give back control to a thread until future quanta.  that's not a whole lot of time.  If something of higher priority needs CPU in that 15-40ms, it gets the time-slice...

Comment: BTW, that's not now `Sleep` behaves.  `Sleep` chooses not to give back control after the time expires (or close to).  It *can't* choose not to "respect" the timeout *when* `Sleep` is called.

Answer (score 7):

`Thread.Sleep` really just calls win32 [Sleep function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), whose documentation details the inaccuracy.

What `Thread.Sleep` really does is give up control for *about* the specified milliseconds. The [Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function details that could be more or less. The rate at which the OS can give back control is determined by the system quantum, which is 10-15 milliseconds. So, in reality `Thread.Sleep` can only be accurate to the nearest quantum. But, as others have pointed out, if the CPU is under heavy load that, time will be longer. Plus, if your thread has a lower priority than all other threads, it may not get time.

In terms of load, it's about load when the switch might occur. You're talking about a 1ms timeout (which is really about 15, as you've witnessed, due to the system quantum or timer accuracy) which means that the OS really only needs to be busy for 15-30 ms before it can be too busy to give back control to a thread until a future quanta. That's not a whole lot of time. If something of higher priority needs CPU in that 15-40ms, the higher-priority threads gets the time-slice, potentially starving the thread that gave up its control.

What `Thread.Sleep` really means (for timeout values larger than 1) is that it's telling the OS that this thread is lower in priority than *every other thread* in the system for *at least* the timeout value, until the thread gets control back.  `Thread.Sleep` is not a timing mechanism, it's a means of relinquishing control.  They should really rename "Sleep" to "Yield".

If you want to design something that periodically does something, use a timer.  If you need to be really precise, use a multimedia timer.

Comment: I've been using it as an interval timer for ever, but not in any way for anything approaching accurate subsecond intervals, (because it won't work - as we know).

Comment: @MartinJames And why would you waste a thread and it's 1 megabyte of stack like that?  What's wrong with a `Timer` class?

Comment: Needs another thread to operate the timer.  More context-swaps.  1MB stack a default, not a lock.  Timer signals much more difficult to implement when several functions/layers down on a stack.  Simplicity.  The calling thread exists anyway.  Elimination of state-engines.  Works out-of-the box.  Trivial typing when nothing more is required.  Available on all multitasking OS.

Comment: It only needs another thread during the Elapsed event, not the entire 60 seconds.  If that's a thread pool thread on which Sleep is called that also forces the threadpool to create a new thread because that one is blocked Sleep.  All that other stuff applies in either case if you want to overcomplicate it--or simply doesn't apply. "trivial typing"?

Answer (score 3):

Windows is not a real time operating system.

The scheduler may wait longer than the requested sleep duration to execute a thread, especially if another thread is still busy.

Try use the Multimedia Timer if you want more reliability. There is a .NET wrapper [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5501/The-Multimedia-Timer-for-the-NET-Framework).

Answer (score 2):

Your program is not guaranteed to be the sole user of a CPU.

Other processes get slices of the CPU - `Thread.Sleep` will make a *best attempt* to resume after the timeout, but if the CPU is busy, it has to wait.

Comment: But why does it behave so randomly, yet keeps its randomly chosen behavior over a longer time period?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to wait, not if you raise the sleeping thread to a higher priority than all other threads.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.Sleep` only guarantees that the thread will sleep for *at least* the specified interval. It does not give accuracy guarantees -- indeed it cannot do so, because it is the OS scheduler that decides when each blocked thread should be given CPU time.

If threads could *demand* that they be run again in a specific point in time then preemptive multitasking would be impossible.

Comment: It does not even seem to sleep for at least the specified interval either. It wakes up early for me, i.e., sleeping for 1 sec often wakes up after 980 msec or so.

Answer (score 2):

Windows isn't a real-time OS, so you won't get those kinds of guarantees.  Basically, Thread.Sleep will sleep for *at least*  milliseconds, but it could be more, especially for very small values.

Comment: This still doesn't answer why it (only) sometimes work. If it works, it works over a longer time period. If it doesn't, it doesn't work over a longer time period. It's not like the behavior is switching every couple milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.Sleep()` is not precise.  The number you give it is the *MINIMUM* time to sleep, not the exact time to sleep.  Further, Thread.Sleep also has a minimum granularity, which I think Is around 10ms IIRC.

If you need more precise timing, then you probably want to use a timer instead.  However, be aware that Windows and .NET in particular are not "Real Time", so they cannot give you pinpoint accuracy.

For example, if the garbage collector kicks in, it may take longer to process timers.

Comment: But then why is `Thread.Sleep()` precise sometimes if the granularity is 10 ms?

Answer (score 0):

You're not the only one to point this out recently.  Something must have changed since XP.  Sleep() was then pretty reliable, and indeed accurate, over intervals where it's useful, eg. seconds or minutes.  4ms is totally outside of what is available via Sleep(), as others have pointed out.

It seems that now, with later OS, some extra uncertainty has crept in somehow, though I haven't tested it myself.

Over usefully long periods, you should raise the priority of the sleeping thread so it will get dispatched as soon as it is made ready by the expiry of the sleep interval.

For 4ms, look at multimedia timers, as suggested by Science Fiction, (+1).

Comment: `Sleep` has never been accurate, even to the next quantum.  You *can* run code that *does* consistently hit the nearest quantum over a small period of time; but that doesn't make it more accurate in invocation, even XP...  It's not like the documentation for the Sleep function has really changed since XP.  Joe Duffy talks about Sleep back in Aug 2006 (http://bit.ly/RICHau), which was based on experience and knowledge of XP, since Vista hadn't been released yet.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - Sure, small sleeps are hopelessly wobbly, but a Sleep(60000) loop on XP was a reasonable minute-timer.  Of course, over time, the overrun due to the timer granularity will add up, but the minute was always about 60 seconds <g>.  There have been a couple posts that suggest that this behaviour has changed and that some extra factor has become involved..  I have not tested it myself since XP, so I have only anecdotes.

Comment: It's reasonable minute timer because if it's off by 15 or event 40ms, it doesn't matter.  That's not a difference in accuracy.  It's still off by 15-40ms...

Comment: Well, I think it's reasonable to say that it's more accurate over 60 seconds than over 6ms!

Comment: No, the percentage error is less over 60 seconds than 6ms, it's not more "accurate".  It's still off by 15-40ms (or whatever number).  Accuracy is defined as "how close the measured value is to the true or accepted value".  If Sleep(6) resulted in a regaining control after 15ms and Sleep(60000) resulted in regaining control after 60009 ms, the accuracy is the same: +9ms;