# Elapsed time measurements bugs

Tags: c#, datetime, stopwatch

Stumbled upon unexpected behaviours during elapsed time measurements.

I've started from `Stopwatch` class:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/3hch1R

But it turned out that every once in a while elapsed time will be less than 200ms.

Then was a time of `DateTime.Now` and it showed something strange as well:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var start = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    var stop = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
    Console.WriteLine(stop - start);    
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/2vo2yw

Thing as simple as this regularly returns negative results.

So my question is: what is the reason of such behaviour for both classes and how can I measure elapsed time more precisely (without negative deviations) ?
There is a [post](http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.co.nz/2008/10/beware-of-stopwatch.html) about stopwatch which shed some light on the topic, but comments there look a bit contradictory.

**Edit1:**
As AlexD spotted, `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` simply returns a millisecond part, not TotalMilliseconds. So this one is clear.

**Edit2:**
Following suggestions, I've decided to go with DateTime, it's results satisfies my precision requirements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var start = (int)DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    var stop = (int)DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine(stop - start);    
}
```

Or `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond` if day changing between measurements is a case for you.

Comment: Thread.Sleep is notoriously innacurate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321225/net-thread-sleep-is-randomly-imprecise

Comment: @Alex I've initially used `System.Threading.Timer`, which showed the same results, so I've decided to use `Thread.Sleep` in examples for space saving sake

Comment: Same answer, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744032/why-are-net-timers-limited-to-15-ms-resolution . I think it's only sleeping for approximately 200ms, which sometimes means a little less.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the first problem. For me `stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` returns values `>= 200` so far.

Comment: where you trying to get like 200,400,600,...so on?

Comment: @AlexD it really depends on both hardware and software (like, I have different results on 2 laptops which I have), so you have to believe me

Comment: A very similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303667/how-accurate-is-thread-sleeptimespan

Comment: Just be aware of midnight problem with `TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds` :).

Comment: @AlexD yeah, sure, it's not the issue for me. Otherwise, it may be changed to `(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it turned out that every once in a while elapsed time will be less than 200ms.

I cannot reproduce your results (neither locally, nor with the link to dotnetfiddle.net),
but anyway `Thread.Sleep` does not look accurate. See e.g. [How accurate is Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1303667).

Maybe a bit off-topic, but for *WINAPI* `Sleep` function MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The system clock "ticks" at a constant rate. If `dwMilliseconds` is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time. If `dwMilliseconds` is greater than one tick but less than two, the wait can be **anywhere between one and two ticks**, and so on.

---

> Thing as simple as this regularly returns negative results.

`DateTime.Now.Millisecond` does not return *total* milliseconds, just milliseconds component.

Comment: True, my bad. This may go off the board

Answer (score 2):

Ad 1: Thread.Sleep is not a very accurate method to sleep... I suggest you use a combination of sleep and busy wait: sleep for, say, 180ms, then use busy wait until you reach 200ms; this will load the CPU 100% during the last 20ms (average CPU load of 10%, which might be reasonable), but will give you more accurate release time.

Ad 2: Use DateTime.Ticks (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns the number of 'ticks' (100ns intervals) that have passed 'since beginning of time'.

Comment: like I said, Thread.Sleep is there only for question space saving. Initially it was System.Theading.Timer. Do you know, does Timer suffers the same problem as Thread.Sleep?